# Calculating the area of each cell of a Dataarray (or Raster) using Python?

Tags: python, raster, xarray

I would like to compute the area of each respective cell of a raster.

The pixels are in degree coordinates, so it is not trivial to calculate the area of each one "manually".

In R I know there is a function for this:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/area

Does anyone have an idea of how can I do it in python?

Comment: Better reproject your raster to a metric CRS. Take the cell resolution times itself (area of one cell) and multiply with the amount of pixels in the raster